# In QgroundControl build remove daily in title bar in stable version 4.2.3 in qt

Tags: qt, github, qt5, mavlink, mission-planner

i am Trying to rebuild my own qgroundcontrol,i want to remove the daily from the title bar and
change the background color of the title bar
i am using
https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/tree/Stable_V4.2

please help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTqH3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:
Stable V4.2

QGCApplication.cc
lines 264-268, specifically in line 267:

> ifdef DAILY_BUILD
>
> ```
>     applicationName = QStringLiteral("%1 Daily").arg(QGC_APPLICATION_NAME);
> ```
>
> #else
> applicationName = QGC_APPLICATION_NAME;

remove the word Daily here.

About the colors:
open QGCPalette.cc
and go to lines 88-90:

```
DECLARE_QGC_NONTHEMED_COLOR(brandingPurple,     "#1E3582", "#1E3582")
DECLARE_QGC_NONTHEMED_COLOR(brandingBlue,       "#878686", "#878686")
DECLARE_QGC_NONTHEMED_COLOR(toolStripFGColor,   "#707070", "#ffffff")
```

change the HEX values here to your colors, for example the top color is the color of the left side of the top title-bar.